# Minimize auto resize image

Tags: html, css

How do I minimize auto resize image on my blog?

These are the codes:

overall_header.html

```
<div class="inventea-dashboard" role="banner">
            <a href="<!-- IF U_SITE_HOME -->{U_SITE_HOME}<!-- ELSE -->{U_INDEX}<!-- ENDIF -->" title="<!-- IF U_SITE_HOME -->{L_SITE_HOME}<!-- ELSE -->{L_INDEX}<!-- ENDIF -->" style="position: absolute; left: 0%;top: 20%; width: 100%; height: 60%;" >
                <div class="inventea-sitename">
                    <h1>{SITENAME}</h1>
                    <span>{SITE_DESCRIPTION}</span>
                </div>
            </a>
            <img src="{ROOT_PATH}styles/we_universal/theme/images/dashboard.jpg" alt="forum header image">
        </div>
```

common.css

```
.inventea-dashboard img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
```

Comment: Minimize in what way, width, height? just set a `min-*`